# How can I use parenthesis while using the (?P<name>...) regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I want to specify something from the expression after the `(?P<name>...)` like:

```
(?P<name>\d.+([a-z]))
```

but it is not allowing me. Is there a way to use the `(?P<name>...)` expression with parenthesis?
Sample text:

```
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
144.23.247.108 - auer7552 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700] "POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/1.1" 100
```

Let's say I only want the date part

```
z=re.finditer('(?P<date>\[\d+.+\])',logdata)
        for l in z:
         print(l.groupdict())
```

this allows me to get the date but with the square brackets, how can I specify that I don't want the square brackets with out using the brackets??
because if I use the brackets an error pops out

```
z=re.finditer('(?P<date>\[(\d+.+)\])',logdata)
        for l in z:
         print(l.groupdict())
```

it just returns the date with square brackets and ignores my parenthesis here

```
import re
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        k=re.finditer('(?P<request>\".+\")',logdata)
        for request in k:
            a=request.groupdict()
        q=re.finditer('(?P<time>\d+/.+\s-\d+)',logdata)
        for time in q:
            b=time.groupdict()
        g=re.finditer('(?P<host>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)',logdata)
        for host in g:
            c=host.groupdict()
        f= re.finditer('(?P<user_name>\s[a-z]+\d+)',logdata)
        for user_name in f:
            d=user_name.groupdict()
        d.update(a)
        d.update(b)
        d.update(c)
        return d
```

that's the code for the entire assignment.

Comment: try `(\(\?P<name>.+\))`

Comment: that doesn't help because I have not excluded the part I don't want. Let's say I want the `.+` but not the slash after it or any other element. This method would not enable me to do that

Comment: what I am trying to do is something like `(.+)/s etc` while naming the title for the dictionary.

Comment: Could you please provide more examples, such as: Example-text that you're trying to match against, Examples of what the end-result of the matching should be, and also the code you've tried that _doesn't_ do what you want it to do.

Comment: can you update the sample output? you want to print the character in between `(?P<name>` and  `)`?

Comment: It's hard for us to know _why_ your regular expression doesn't work, because we can only see what your example is _trying_ to match against. As you can see in [this example](https://regex101.com/r/xLrl2E/2) You can use your regular expression to match against something.

Comment: @Ramesh yes but not all of it, only certain parts of the expression.

Comment: @MamdouhDabjan your expected result?

Comment: In the example I gave above I just want the date part  which is `21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700` without the square brackets, but I don't know how to do that without using parenthesis. Normally I would just use `\[(d+.+)\])` to get rid of the square brackets but it is returning an error in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pattern `(.*?)` to match anything inside brackets.

```
import re

regex = r'\[(.*?)\]'

text = '''197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
168.95.156.240 - stark2413 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700] "GET /engage HTTP/2.0" 201 9645
71.172.239.195 - dooley1853 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700] "PUT /cutting-edge HTTP/2.0" 406 24498
180.95.121.94 - mohr6893 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700] "PATCH /extensible/reinvent HTTP/1.1" 201 27330
144.23.247.108 - auer7552 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700] "POST /extensible/infrastructures/one-to-one/enterprise HTTP/1.1" 100'''

#print(re.findall(regex, text))

test = []
data = re.finditer(regex, text)
for i in data:
    test.append(i.group(1))
print(test)

>>> ['21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:31 -0700', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:32 -0700', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:34 -0700', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:35 -0700']
```

this will return all updated dict keys and values:

```
def logs():
    logdata = '''197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
'''
    log_data = logdata.split('\n')
    dict_lst = []
    for log in log_data:
        d = {}
        k = re.finditer('(?P<request>\".+\")', log)
        for request in k:
            a = request.groupdict()
            d.update(a)
        q = re.finditer('(?P<time>\d+/.+\s-\d+)', logdata)
        for time in q:
            b = time.groupdict()
            d.update(b)
        g = re.finditer('(?P<host>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', logdata)
        for host in g:
            c = host.groupdict()
            d.update(c)
        f = re.finditer('(?P<user_name>\s[a-z]+\d+)', logdata)
        for user_name in f:
            e = user_name.groupdict()
            d.update(e)
        dict_lst.append(d)
    return dict_lst
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I want to combine that with `finditer` to make it a dictionary with values as text and a key as 'date'.

Comment: you can use the same regex and match the group(1) it will do fine.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Could you help me with something else?? I am trying to do the assignment above but I need to make a dictionary with 4 separate things. host, name, time, request. I created the necessary regular expressions , but I am struggling with inserting them all in a dictionary. The method you gave me gives me a list that I can use. The main problem is that I am supposed to make that a function, but when I try to return the answer that I got, it only returns the first row of the dictionary, even if printing it inside the function works. How can I solve it?

Comment: the dictionary I got from this is : `{'user_name': ' feest6811', 'request': '"PUT /one-to-one/whiteboard HTTP/1.0"', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:16:02:02 -0700', 'host': '30.95.91.251'}
{'user_name': ' kertzmann3129', 'request': '"PUT /one-to-one/whiteboard HTTP/1.0"', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:16:02:02 -0700', 'host': '30.95.91.251'}`but when I try and type return dic so I can just type the function and it extracts this, it only prints out the first row.

Comment: you have to store the values in dictionary before the for loop. kindly the update the code so that we can corect your code.

Comment: I uploaded the code i was using. How can I make this work?

Comment: your are updating the values with same key pair resulting in overwritten. will update the solution